# OCR (reading text from photos) in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4

Is there any code out there, that I can use in Cocoa, to recognize text from photos? Let's say I snap a photo with my iPhone of a page of a book. I'd like to capture the text in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) toolkit that is an open source OCR engine, currently maintained by Google. "Olipion" created a [cross compilation tutorial](http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr) to get in on the iPhone. I would say that this is a good place to start.

However, there are reasons why you might not want to to OCR on the Phone even if you could. Some of these include:

- Even the new iPhone 4's processor is not that fast and since you app can't really run in the background doing the processing, the user experience might not be optimal.
- Running OCR on a mobile device would probably be a killer for battery life.
- Every time you would want to update the OCR engine everybody who installed your app would have to upgrade.

For an always connected mobile device running the OCR on a server somewhere would be probably better. You could upgrade your OCR software easily, you could run much more powerful algorithms then a mobile device could handle and so on.

I am not so sure that you would be able to get good results from photos taken using a mobile camera -- accuracy of OCR systems goes way down with the kind of poorly lit, noisy, distorted images likely to be captured using a phone camera.

As far as commercial products out there, there is [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/premium/#) that gives you a OCR capability if you buy their premium service.

As an alternative to machine OCR, there is always [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome), where you could pay people small amount to do the OCR for you. Would probably do better at transcription given the image source.

Comment: The http://weocr.ocrgrid.org/ project claims to provide infrastructure for network OCRing.

Comment: here is a github project of tesseract OCR working on ios https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

Comment: Wow, I tried the demo ... and this Tesseract algorithm turns out to work really shitty. It reads mostly gibberish with sometimes an actual word in between all the mess. Too bad :(

Comment: Oh, apparently you need to do lots of image preprocessing before feeding it to Tesseract like skewing and noise reduction. Does anyone know how to do those things in iOS?

Comment: What OCR should be used in macOS. The tesseract has support to iOS app but not to cocoa development. Does anyone know a OCR that can be used in my mac App?