# Translate image into plain text - iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm

I want to create an app where the user takes a photo and then the app translates that image into text based on what the user took a picture of. For example: If the user took a picture of a book then the app would then translate that into plain text.

Where would I start with something like this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision

Comment: Check related questions on using OCR libraries in Cocoa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289744/ocr-reading-text-from-photos-in-cocoa

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Answer (score 1):

If you 'just' want to read an image of text into a string, look for [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

If you want to really have a computer *describe* what's in the picture.. With some background in computer vision I feel qualified to state that that's not possible with current technology.

So, if you want that, what are your options? You could do like [mealsnap](http://dashdingo.org/post/4391031302/how-mealsnap-works), and use cheap micro-labor from [mechanical turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IQEngines](http://www.iqengines.com/).  It combines computer vision and crowdsourcing to figure out what's in the image.

We use it at [Voxy](http://voxy.com) (a language learning company) to help users create flashcards when they're learning English and don't know what the word is.

Comment: Better answer than mine; It basically uses a similar method, but is built with exactly this problem in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have used one OCR in one of my app - http://www.abbyy.com/Default.aspx?DN=5b0ab341-0c6e-4119-a824-c652b9e888f4

And here is a REST based api for OCR - http://www.wisetrend.com/wisetrend_ocr_cloud.shtml